# Android Studio GDX, Black Screen after Splash Screen

Tags: libgdx, splash-screen

**When my splash screen has faded in and then out I'm doing this:**

```
((Game) Gdx.app.getApplicationListener()).setScreen(new MainMenu(game));
```

**But I get a black screen.**

**This is the Splash Screen:**

```
public class SplashScreen implements Screen {

private SpriteBatch batch;
private Sprite splash;
private TweenManager tweenManager;
private static RunningGame game;

public SplashScreen(RunningGame g) {
    game = g;
}

@Override
public void show() {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    tweenManager = new TweenManager();
    Tween.registerAccessor(Sprite.class, new SpriteAccessor());

    splash = new Sprite(new Texture("splash.png"));

    Tween.set(splash, SpriteAccessor.ALPHA).target(0).start(tweenManager);
    Tween.to(splash, SpriteAccessor.ALPHA, 1.5f).target(1).repeatYoyo(1, .5f).setCallback(new TweenCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onEvent(int type, BaseTween<?> source) {
            ((Game) Gdx.app.getApplicationListener()).setScreen(new MainMenu(game));
        }
    }).start(tweenManager);

    tweenManager.update(Float.MIN_VALUE);
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    batch.begin();
    splash.draw(batch);
    batch.end();

    tweenManager.update(delta);
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void hide() {
        dispose();

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    batch.dispose();
    splash.getTexture().dispose();
}
}
```

**This is the Main Menu Screen that's not showing up:**

```
public class MainMenu implements Screen {

private Stage stage;
private Skin skin;
private Table table;
private static RunningGame game;

public MainMenu(RunningGame g) {
    game = g;
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    stage.act(delta);
    stage.draw();


}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    table.invalidateHierarchy();
}

@Override
public void show() {
    stage = new Stage();

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

    skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("ui/menuSkin.json"), new TextureAtlas("ui/atlas.pack"));

    table = new Table(skin);
    table.setFillParent(true);


    TextButton buttonPlay = new TextButton("PLAY", skin, "big");

    buttonPlay.addListener(new ClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
            stage.addAction(sequence(moveTo(0, -stage.getHeight(), .5f), run(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ((Game) Gdx.app.getApplicationListener()).setScreen(new PlayScreen(MainMenu.game));
                }
            })));
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void hide() {
    dispose();
}

@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    stage.dispose();
    skin.dispose();
}

}
```

**In case the JSON file is the error:**

```
{
  "com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color": {
    "white": { "r": 1, "g": 1, "b": 1, "a": 1 },
    "black": { "r": 0, "g": 0, "b": 0, "a": 1 },
    "gray":  { "r": 0.3, "g": 0.3, "b": 0.3, "a": 1 },
    "red":   { "r": 1, "g": 0, "b": 0, "a": 1 },
    "green": { "r": 0, "g": 1, "b": 0, "a": 1 },
    "blue":  { "r": 0, "g": 0, "b": 1, "a": 1 }
  },
  "com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont": {
    "white64": { "file": "font/white64.fnt" },
    "black64": { "file": "font/black64.fnt" },
    "white32": { "file": "font/white32.fnt" },
    "black32": { "file": "font/black32.fnt" },
    "white16": { "file": "font/white16.fnt" },
    "black16": { "file": "font/black16.fnt" }
  },
  "com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label$LabelStyle": {
    "default": { "font": "white32", "fontColor": "white" },
    "big":     { "font": "white64", "fontColor": "white" },
    "small":   { "font": "white16", "fontColor": "white" }
  },
  "com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton$TextButtonStyle": {
    "default": { "up": "button.up", "down": "button.down", "font": "black32", "pressedOffsetX": 1, "pressedOffsetY": -1 },
    "big":     { "up": "button.up", "down": "button.down", "font": "black64", "pressedOffsetX": 1, "pressedOffsetY": -1 },
    "small":   { "up": "button.up", "down": "button.down", "font": "black16", "pressedOffsetX": 1, "pressedOffsetY": -1 }
  },
  "com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.List$ListStyle": {
    "default": { "font": "white32", "fontColorUnselected": "white", "fontColorSelected": "black", "selection": "default.selection" }
  },
  "com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.ScrollPane$ScrollPaneStyle": {
    "default": { "hScrollKnob": "button.up", "vScrollKnob": "button.up" }
  },
  "com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.CheckBox$CheckBoxStyle": {
    "default": { "font": "white32", "checkboxOn": "checkbox.on", "checkboxOff": "checkbox.off", "checkboxOver": "checkbox.over" }
  },
  "com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextField$TextFieldStyle": {
    "default": { "font": "black32", "fontColor": "black", "messageFontColor": "gray", "background": "default.background", "cursor": "default.selection" }
  }
}
```

Comment: There is nothing in your stage except an empty table. You created a button, but didn't put it in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like  Tenfour04 already stated, you created a stage, and did not add anything to it. Also you did not set the button position.

If you want the button inside the table:

```
  //Setting table bounds
  table.setBounds(0,0,Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
  //Adding button to table
  table.add(buttonPlay).width(20).height(20);
  // Adding table to stage
  stage.addActor(table);
```

If you want the button outside the table(table is not needed):

```
  //Setting button size
  buttonPlay.setSize(80,80);
  //Setting button position
  buttonPlay.setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2 - buttonPlay.getWidth()/2,10);
  // Adding button to stage
  stage.addActor(buttonPlay);
```